# How to select content of span class tag in python

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

```
<span class="labels">
            <a href="/misp/securehomegateway-router/issues?q=is%3Aopen+is%3Apr+label%3AHCL" class="label v-align-text-top labelstyle-006b75 linked-labelstyle-006b75" style="background-color: #006b75; color: #fff;" title="Label: HCL">HCL</a>
        </span>
      <div class="mt-1 text-small text-gray">
        <span class="opened-by">
          #405
            opened <relative-time datetime="2017-12-14T06:30:48Z">Dec 14, 2017</relative-time> by
            <a href="/misp/securehomegateway-router/issues?q=is%3Apr+is%3Aopen+author%3Assen" class="muted-link" title="Open pull requests created by ssen">ssen</a>

        </span>
```

I want to access datetime. How can I do this?

Comment: It's pretty damn simple once you've read the docs, which I'm guessing you haven't?

Comment: what output did you exactly wants ??